# pulling and element for a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python

first i am new to python and doing an assignment for class
i am writing a program where i make a dictionary with the following information
**child** andrew,betsy,louise,chad
**mother** jane,eleen,natalie,mary
**father** john,nigel,louis,joseph.
It says to use a list for the value so i wrote it

```
    dic={ "child": ["andrew", "betsy", "louise", "chad"],
          "mother": ["jane", "ellen", "natalie", "mary"],
          "father": ["john", "nigel", "louis", "joseph"]}
```

now the idea is that the program will give you options if you would like to know the mother,father, or both. then you enter the childs name and it gives you the corresponding mother,father, or both.
but i am just trouble shooting at the moment and want to know how could i call a element of each list with it in a dictionary like this
for instance say i wanted to make it print andrew if i put print

```
print dic["child"]
```

it will print that whole list but how can i make it just print the one in the [0] position i tried

```
print dic["child"[0]]
```

and

```
print dic["child"(0)]
```

both give an error.

Comment: You need to clarify your idea, both for our understanding and for your own good. If you want a mapping of people to their parents, make a mapping of people to their parents. I don't understand your second question, assuming you know basic dictionary syntax. What's wrong with `print dic['child'][0]`?

Comment: thanks you i was just wanting to know how to make it print what i want for trouble shooting i am very new at this still but the way you wrote it does work

Comment: how would you make the mapping? just curious, the idea is that someone can say i wanna look up mom,dad, or mom and dad. then they enter the childs name and it gives theme the corresponding option either the mom,dad, or both.

Comment: How about this format? `child2parents = {'childname1': {'father': 'fathername1', 'mother': 'mothername1'}, 'childname2': {'father': 'fathername2', 'mother': 'mothername2'}}`. Then you could do `child2parents['childname2']['father']`, for example.

Comment: this is exactly what i need thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You're indexing is incorrect you should be indexing like so `print dict['child'][0]`

Doing `dict['child'[0]])` is indexing the *string* "child" so your passing the key `c` to the dictionary which doesn't actually have this key inside the dict.

`dict['child']` is grabbing the value of the dictionaries key "child". So, when you print this you'll see the entire list of values, and when you do

```
dict['child'][0]
```

you're indexing this list of values so you'll see the correct value "andrew"

Comment: Yeah that's great, dictionaries can be a bit weird at first haha. Just remember to correct his answer.